# How to use select to read input from stdin?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, stdin, fgets

I am trying to read from `stdin` using `select`, after that I am sending the data through a socket to a server.

The following snippet is supposed to follow the above logic; but it doesn't read anything from `stdin`.

Moreover it prints `Enter command:` after the first time the user inputs a string. The line `printf("%d %s\n",__LINE__ ,buf);` doesn't print anything as either.

```
fd_set rfds;
struct timeval tv;
int retval; 
char buf[BUFLEN];
while(1) {
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rfds);
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    retval = select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &rfds)) {
        if (fgets(buf,BUFLEN, stdin)) {
              printf("%d %s\n",__LINE__ ,buf);
          if (strncmp(buf, "exit", 4) == 0)
                exit(0);
         }
         printf("\nEnter command: ");
    }
}
```

why do I get only `Enter command:` printed endlessly ?

**Edit:** *the problem was with the embedded device I was using and somehow compile it with `-fpic` fixed the problem.*

Comment: Add `fflush(NULL);` just before the `select` (and also the `FD_ZERO` and `FD_SET` ....) or better use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead of `select`

Comment: Are you pressing enter after the command?

Comment: In your code you are using `strncmp(p->buf,...`.  Did you mean to use `strncmp(buf,...)`?

Comment: @VaughnCato it is not the problem! I simplified the code... that is not the issue here...

Comment: I tried this and it works: http://ideone.com/SA8MCa

Comment: @VaughnCato check this output: http://ideone.com/SA8MCa#ul_inouterr

Comment: @0x90 If you are trying to do a test, to later implement `select` when using sockets. It will be a good idea to understand `pselect` instead. `pselect` is similar to `select`, however it allows you to break out of itself, when a signal is received.

Comment: @0x90: you never entered "exit"

Comment: Just compiled your code, with BUFLEN defined as 100, and it works fine as posted.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rfds);
```

Inside the while loop

Comment: thanks man but it doesn't solve the problem even though you are right. edited my question.