# Detecting timeout when reading from stdout of running process in D language

Tags: process, stdout, d

I have written a console application in D programming language. It executes some process and reads from its stdout (I use `ProcessPipes`):

```
foreach (line; pipes.stdout.byLine)
{
 writeln(line);                     
}
```

I'd like to detect a 10 seconds timeout (no new lines received). What approach should I use?

Comment: Non-blocking IO, then keep track of every time you read and if last read time exceeds 10 seconds then you simply don't read anymore and can do what you want (Close file handlers etc.) -- I don't have a concrete example for D though.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use `select` if your are on a unix box and `WaitForSingleObject` on Windows to check for available input on the stdin handle, specifying a timeout value. The return value of the calls will tell you if input was available or if it actually timed out.

It might not work right with the buffering that byLine (and underneath that, FILE*) does inside... but it might, I'd say try it first. Just put the call to select/WaitForSingleObject at the end of the loop and see if it fails when it isn't supposed to.

But to be really sure, you can use the lower-level read functions on the input yourself, and break it into lines yourself (or better yet, avoid breaking it into lines if you don't really have to and just use random sized blocks of data as returned from the lower level read functions). Then there will be no weird buffering that the wait functions don't know about, so all will work brilliantly.

You can find examples for these functions from C easily like the official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject or random stack overflow questions with relevant examples [How to use select to read input from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510831/how-to-use-select-to-read-input-from-stdin)

just in D it is `import core.sys.posix.unistd;` or `import core.sys.windows.windows;` instead of the C `#include<unistd.h>` etc.